# ASP.NET MVC2 Routing IIS6 - only default routes work

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis-6, asp.net-mvc-routing, default

I've deployed an ASP.NET MVC2 website on a Windows Server 2003 machine running IIS 6.
I'm using pretty much the default routing in a standard MVC project:

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            "Default", // Route name
            "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
            new { controller = "Products", action = "List", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
        );

    }
```

Navigating to http://localhost/MyApplication takes me to the List page just fine. Navigating to http://localhost/MyApplication/Products/Details/21 gives me a 404. This routing worked fine on the inbuilt development server in VS2010.

I've put in the standard IIS wildcard aspnet_isapi.dll mapping mentioned all over the place - navigating to the List page didn't work before I did - but navigating to anything other than the default route is broken.

I'd really like to keep my extensionless URLs. Does anyone have any idea as to why the routing would work for the default webpage, but no others?

*Edit: just tried adding the .aspx extension, ie now my route looks like this:

```
        routes.MapRoute(
            "Default", // Route name
            "{controller}.aspx/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
            new { controller = "Downtime", action = "List", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
        );
```

And it has the same behaviour, except this time I get the asp 404 page instead of the html 404 page...

*Edit 2: tried it again using the following route and making sure .mvc was mapped to aspnet_isapi.dll:

```
        routes.MapRoute(
            "Default", // Route name
            "{controller}.mvc/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
            new { controller = "Downtime", action = "List", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
        );
```

This time I got an 'Internet Explorer cannot display the webpage' 404-style page. I've now got 3 different 404 errors from using these 3 different methods...

*Edit 3 Return of the Edit: I have the site running in IIS 5.1 on Windows XP professional with only a wildcard remapping on the virtual directory, but heaven forbid I can get it to run on the webserver...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it - the routing is actually working, my URLs were not. I was using javascript to build some of the URLs and it turns out that I wasn't linking to

http: //localhost/MyApplication/Controller/Action/ID

I was actually linking to

http: //localhost/Controller/Action/ID

Building the links like this was working on the development server, but once the site was deployed to a virtual directory on the webserver those addresses are incorrect because of the extra application name in the URL.

In conclusion, be careful with your URLs - don't build them out of strings like I did.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you should follow this walk-through: http://haacked.com/archive/2008/11/26/asp.net-mvc-on-iis-6-walkthrough.aspx

(just to make sure you've not missed something). This shows how to get the extension-less and extention'd versions working. You might want to at least check whether the extension'd version works to check that other things aren't misconfigured.

After that, perhaps you should try adding something like this..

http://haacked.com/archive/2008/03/13/url-routing-debugger.aspx

... as it can really help in determining where your routes are broken.

Some other things to check:

- Is IIS configured with ASP.NET? Check properties of the virtual directory. On the VDir select the configuration button and check that the usual ASP.NET extensions are mapped to the .NET 2.0 ISAPI dll. This will be something along the lines of

  C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\aspnet_isapi.dll.
- Is  ASP.NET 2  enabled on IIS (under IIS 6 this is off by default): in IIS manager check the Web Service Extensions folder to enable it.
- Have you deployed global.asax?

Comment: I've already followed the section in that exact walkthrough for IIS6 Extension-less URLs (hence I mentioned 'the standard IIS wildcard aspnet_isapi.dll mapping mentioned all over the place') but it still won't route to anything other than the default.

Comment: Just edited the parent - adding the extension to my URL doesn't help. The extensionless method worked on the development server. Would that routing debugger help if the routing is correct but there's something wonky in the way IIS 6 is dealing with it?

Comment: All the standard application extensions are there and mapped to aspnet_isapi.dll, ASP.net 2.0.etc is allowed in IIS Web Service Extensions, and global.asax is deployed in the virtual directory. Thanks for the suggestions, but I'm still at a loss. I'm trying to think what it means that navigating to the h ttp://localhost/MyApp root directory actually works, it brings up a page that MUST have been directed to by the default route (it's not called default or index and it's not configured as a default content page) - but nothing else does.

Comment: Found it - see below. Is there any way I can give you points for being helpful and giving concise, relevant advice even if the answer turned out to be something else?